# XSL IF test a condition stored in a variable?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a recursive template that builds a complex OR test condition. Its result is stored in the `$filtercriteria` variable producing a value of:

```
contains(@Category,'abc') or contains(@Category,'def')
```

How do I use this test condition, which is stored in a variable, in an XSL IF statement?

I want the literal value of `$filtercriteria` to be evaluated as the test condition:

```
<xsl:if test="$filtercriteria">
    Do something...
</xsl:if>
```

Should be translated to:

```
<xsl:if test="contains(@Category,'abc') or contains(@Category,'def')">
    Do something...
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: As Martin says, you can't do this in pure XSLT until 3.0. I suspect there is a better way of solving the problem. Why are you building up the condition in this way?

Answer (score 1):

With pure XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 you can't construct XPath expressions as a string and evaluate them. For that you need an extension like http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/ or you need an XSLT 3.0 processor with `xsl:evaluate`: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

When I need `xsl:evaluate` but extensions or XSLT 3.0 aren't options, I go meta and write XSLT to generate new XSLT that itself incorporates the composed statements or expressions.